# How to install systemd service on nixos

Tags: nix, nixos

If I do this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e;

cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"

ln -sf "$(pwd)/interos-es-mdb.service" '/etc/systemd/system/interos-es-mdb.service'

systemctl enable interos-es-mdb.service
systemctl start interos-es-mdb.service
```

then I get this error:

> ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/systemd/system/interos-es-mdb.service': Read-only file system

anyone know the right way to install a service on nixos machine? (I am the root user)...here is the service for reference:

```
[Unit]
Description=Interos MongoDB+ES log capture
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=interos_emit_only_json=yes
EnvironmentFile=/root/interos/env/es-service.env
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/root/interos/repos/elastic-search-app/syslog-exec.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**update:**
perhaps what I am looking for is "per-user" service, not something run as root etcetera.

Comment: ...so the goal is to add new content defining this service to `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`, I assume? (That *is* the Right Way to do it).

Comment: BTW, not related to your question, but `$(pwd)` is bad form -- use `$PWD` instead, which is vastly more efficient -- and `set -e` is... [rightly controversial](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes I guess configuration.nix is the right way..if you can add a simple answer with a link that'd be good enough thanks

Comment: Could you edit the question to include your `.service` file so I can translate it appropriately?

Comment: Also -- you built a derivation for Interos... right?

Comment: not sure what you mean by derivation, but I just added the service contents to the OP, thx

Comment: ...so, a Nix "derivation" is what other operating systems would call a description of a package -- like a PKGBUILD on Arch, or a spec file to build a RPM on Red Hat.

Comment: In your configuration.nix, you should be referring to your software relative to the directory built by the derivation.

Comment: ...so, for example, you might tell your service to start `"${pkgs.elasticsearch-curator}/bin/curator"`, and it'll find the `curator` binary under the `/nix/store` directory created by building the `pkgs.elasticsearch-curator` derivation.

Comment: Re: hardcoding "/root/interos" -- don't do that; installing software by hand rather than building derivations defeats the whole point of using NixOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An appropriate entry in your `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` might look like:

```
let
  # assumes you build a derivation for your software and put it in
  # /etc/nixos/pkgs/interosEsMdb/default.nix
  interosEsMdb = import ./pkgs/interosEsMdb {};
in config.systemd.services.interosEsMdb = {
  description = "Interos MongoDB+ES log capture";
  after = ["network.target"];
  wantedBy = ["multi-user.target"];

  serviceConfig = {
    # change this to refer to your actual derivation
    ExecStart = "${interosEsMdb}/bin/syslog-exec.sh";
    EnvironmentFile = "${interosEsMdb}/lib/es-service.env";
    Restart = "always";
    RestartSec = 1;
  }
}
```

...assuming you actually build a derivation for `interosEsMdb` (which is the only sane and proper way to package software on NixOS).

Comment: yeah there are some services running on some of our nixos machines and there is no reference to those services in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`..idk

Comment: Typically, there'll be a module that turns on the service based on things that *are* in `configuration.nix`.

Comment: we have a bunch of services running as a user called "backend" (as opposed to root user), and the configuration.nix file literally has this content in it's entiriety: 

`[root@ec2-52-27-xx-xxx:~]# cat /etc/nixos/configuration.nix
{
  imports = [ <nixpkgs/nixos/modules/virtualisation/amazon-image.nix> ];
  ec2.hvm = true;

}`

Comment: To give you an example, I wrote the NixOS `bees` module, but you don't need to set up `config.systemd.services.bees`; instead, whenever you set up configuration in `config.services.beesd`, the code at https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/services/misc/bees.nix sets up the appropriate services for you.

Comment: Ahh -- now, *per-user* services are a different thing entirely.

Comment: yes perhaps they are, so I can update OP to make it about per-user services because that's what I want I think, thx

Comment: maybe just leave this answer, and add a second answer, and preface the answers with your assumptions thanks

Comment: Take a look at `~/.local/share/systemd/user/` and `~/.config/systemd/user/` for the `backend` account. That said, if that content isn't *itself* being assembled by Nix, the folks who set  it up are, again, Doing It Wrong.

Comment: ("doing it wrong" meaning not getting the benefits in reproducibility, atomicity, versioning, &c. that are the whole point of using NixOS).

Comment: (...as in, if you're not going to use it right, why use it at all?)

Comment: nixos is very cool, but at this point I just want to get something working..I am just trying to install a service that reads from syslog and writes to the network..if nixos wants mindshare..it needs to make things easy (or just make things hard, why not  lol)

Comment: also, I am curious, where the env vars for `"${interosEsMdb}/bin/syslog-exec.sh" `would come from. where would `interosEsMdb` get set?

Comment: That's what the `import` in the `let` is for, to load a definition of `interosEsMdb` from a separate file on disk (where you presumably wrote a Nix  derivation describing where to download that software and how to unpack and compile it -- the hash of that downloaded software, and of those unpack/install steps, being used to generate the directory name under `/nix/store` where the resulting software lives).

Comment: Honestly, I don't give much of a @#% about behaving like operating systems that don't give you atomicity, rollback support, ability to ask *why* and *how* configuration changed between two points in time, etc -- if supporting letting users mutate the system in-place gives up all the benefits that make NixOS (and GUIX) unique, why would we do that? People who don't care about those capabilities and want something that works like every other OS have no shortage of choices available to them.

Comment: ...the whole reason NixOS has capabilities that no other OS (except GUIX) has is that it enforces those rules. Give up the rules, you give up the properties that fall out from having them.

Answer (score 16):

## The reason its broken

NixOS is a declarative operating system. This means that directories like `/etc` live inside the read-only `/nix/store` directory. Only the nix-daemon is allowed to mount the nix-store as writable. Therefore, you must create a `systemd.services.<yourservice>` entry in your `configuration.nix` to interact with the underlying system; alternatively you can patch [nixpkgs](https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs) directly and point your configuration to your fork.

All *running* services not declared explicitly by the user can be assumed to live inside [`nixpkgs/nixos/modules`](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/master/nixos/modules).

## Fix

`configuration.nix:`

```hs
{
  systemd.services.foo = {
    enable = true;
    description = "bar";
    unitConfig = {
      Type = "simple";
      # ...
    };
    serviceConfig = {
      ExecStart = "${foo}/bin/foo";
      # ...
    };
    wantedBy = [ "multi-user.target" ];
    # ...
  };
}
```

### *user services*

almost identical except they begin with `systemd.user.services`. In addition, user home directories are not managed declartively, so you can also place a regular systemd unit file under `$XDG_CONFIG_DIR/systemd` as usual.

## relevant:

Full list of valid attributes for [`systemd.services.<name>`](https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html#opt-systemd.services._name_.enable), *From: NixOS Manual*

[Module basics](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Module), *From: Wiki*

Comment: are those parens balanced in the haskell? i don't know much about haskell

Comment: sorry, but what's this about haskell? The code above is written in the [nix](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ch-expression-language) expression language

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I think Type = "simple" is part of the service config, not the unit config.

Comment: @user11810894 concearn is the accolade on line "systemd.services.foo = {" seems to have a missing closing accolade '}'